# Extracting items from a tuple in dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am just a beginner to pyspark  and data frames 
my dtaframe is `df([('one',1),('two',2),('three',3)],[('four',4)])`
so i want to concatenate x to each of the first elements in the tuple .
ex `onex, twox,threex,fourx`.
any help is appreciated .
`df.select()` is only giving the items in the first list . 
mk

Comment: It is impossible that you construct a DataFrame from `df([('one',1),('two',2),('three',3)],[('four',4)])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def append_x(val):
    return val + 'x'

df = df.withColumn(
    'appended',
    udf(append_x, StringType())(col(colInput))
)
```

Note that `colInput` is the name of column you want to append `x` to.